# What would be the possible causes for the type error: function () got multiple values for keyword argument?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to use keyword argument instead of positional argument. However, it repeatedly displays the following type error: function () got multiple values for the argument.

I tried to verify the code using a positional argument and removing the space after the comma that separates the two arguments with the expectation of solved error. Nevertheless, the same repeated message appeared actually.

Comment: Please include a specific example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: def greet_user(first_name, last_name):
    print(f'hi {first_name} {last_name}!')
    print("welcome aboard")


print("start")
greet_user("smith",  first_name = "jhon")
print("finish")